# Django - How to design a Django website with subdomains?

Tags: django, subdomain

I'm new to Django...

I will develop a web application that will have subdomains like "us.mysite.com", "uk.mysite.com", "es.mysite.com". I have many doubts about the better way of doing this in Django...

Should I design my Django project by Apps like this:

```
mysite_project
        --> uk_app
        --> us_app
        --> es_app
```

If not, what should I do? One Django Projecto for each subdomain?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Using Subdomains in Django](http://thingsilearned.com/2009/01/05/using-subdomains-in-django/).

Answer (score 0):

Is [Using Subdomains](http://thingsilearned.com/2009/01/05/using-subdomains-in-django/) better than using [this](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? (I don't know the answer--these were the two resources I found, and I'm confused by both.)  Which is better/easier?  (Hopefully the same answer to both questions, but...)